How to update list value according given value
In below mlist object, how does one update the value to 'character' for all elements which currently are c("ordered", "factor")?
library(tidyverse)
mlist <- sapply(diamonds,class) 

mlist[['color']] <- 'character' can just update one of them. Is there any way to update all of them at once?
mlist[['color']] <- 'character'


Try mlist[sapply(diamonds, is.ordered)] = "character"

Here is the quickest way that I can think of:
# Positions where `mlist` has the value `c("ordered", "factor").
pos <- which(sapply(mlist, function(x) identical(x, c("ordered", "factor"))))
# Change these
mlist[pos] <- "character"
# Result
mlist

Note that this doesn't change the class variable of your data set but merely the values is the list mlist that you generated.

Here is a tidyverse way of doing this:
library(purrr)

modify_if(mlist, ~ all(.x %in% c("ordered", "factor")), ~ "character")

